# Multisite Manager. Adding a second site question

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager

Just a quick question really to anyone who has added a second or third site with EE and MSM. When integrating the second site is there a way round of allowing the client to carry on updating the first site.

Or is it a case of what we are doing now and stopping the client from updating until the integration of second site has been completed?

Any views would be greatly appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the client isn't in the Super Admins member group, you could remove control panel access from the member groups in which the client account(s) reside.

See the [Member Groups documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-access-the-control-panel) for the various permission settings you can assign or take away from groups.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Jeremy's answer is to change the password(s) for the control panel login(s) the client uses. If they can't login, they can't change anything.